# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, macos-catalina

I am getting this error message: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

The code is here:
I have given the cell an Identifier name in the storyboard... can anyone see what is going wrong here?

Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    
    let toDoItem = toDoItems[row]
    if tableColumn?.identifier == "importantColumn.Strong"{
        print("STRONG")
    }
```

[Image of Identifier name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C2YD.png)

Comment: where is exactly do you get the error message? Is it in one of the lines you posted? If so, which one? What is the type of `toDoItems`?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier` with a `String`.

I guess you want:

```
tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "importantColumn.Strong"
```

or

```
tableColumn?.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "importantColumn.Strong")
```